# Python.Net not resolving Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: python, python.net

I'm trying to load Microsoft.Data.SqlClient using Python.net. I have unpacked the dll into at directory like this:

[image: my directory]

```
assembly_path = r"C:\Users\mike\Projects\Python\pythonnet\microsoft.data.sqlclient.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"  
import sys  
sys.path.append(assembly_path)  
import clr  
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient")  
from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient import SqlConnection
```

I'm getting: unresolved import 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient'Python(unresolved-import)
I've practised on a few System assemblies and they work fine, this is all Windows 10.
What have I forgotten to do?

Comment: I chopped the dll name off the end and put \\ at the end of the path string and I've had a little luck and moved onto Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll'

Comment: Clearly you need to add all the dependencies of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to the search path too. One way to do it is to make an empty dotnet console app, reference the package, then do `dotnet publish --framework net471`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I have tried putting the sni dll on the path but I wondered if it needed something else